# SQLAlchemy Generate ER Diagram

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, erd

I am trying to generate an ER diagram from a flask-sqlalchemy database using sqlalchemy-schemadisplay. But it gives me a object of type 'MetaData' have no len() error. Does schemadisplay work on flask-sqlalchmey?

[image: Picture of the code]

[image: Picture of the error]